# Suggest ways in which this Acmf image denoising algorithm could be further improved

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I want to improve this algorithm further so that my final output is closer to the original image, able to cope up with all blurring effects and have more clarification. How can I do it? I am attaching my code in here:

```
function X = ACmf(A)
    A = double(A);
    
    % Adaptive Cesàro Mean Filtering
    for p = 5:-1:1  
        pA = padarray(A, [p p], 'symmetric');
        pB = (pA ~= 0 & pA ~= 255);
        [m, n] = size(pB);
        for i = 1 + p:m - p
            for j = 1 + p:n - p       
                if (pB(i, j) == 0)          
                    for k = 1:p
                        if (isequal(pB(i - k:i + k, j - k:j + k), zeros(2 * k + 1, 2 * k + 1)) ~= 1)             
                            R1 = pA(i - k:i + k, j - k:j + k);
                            R2 = R1(R1 > 0 & R1 < 255);
                            A(i - p, j - p) = mean(R2);
                            break;
                        end
                    end
                end
            end 
        end   
    end

    X = uint8(A);
end
```

My output is fine. But I want to modify this algorithm further. I am expecting a much clearer output so that I can apply it to any type of images.